# How to use $transitions.onStart() in Angular 8?

Tags: angular

I have an issue when try to migrate project written by AngularJS to Angular 8, how I can migrate the code below to Angular 8:

**For AngularJS**:

```
// `transition start` text only show once when I redirect the url

this.$transitions.onStart({}, (transition) => {
    console.log('transition start');
});
```

**For Angular 8**:

```
// I try to convert the code above to this one but when I redirect the url, `transition start` will show twice or even more than

this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
   if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
     console.log('transition start');
   }
});
```

Does anyone have same the issue and any idea about that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try unsubscribing to the event:

```
onRouteChange() {
    this._routeListener = this.router.events.subscribe((event) => ...);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
    this._routeListener.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: In fact, it will never call twice, except we were wrong structural for router, my case was wrong structural the router. Thank you Akash!